# How can I take the Token Test?

Tags: methodology, test

I want to take the Token Test

Is there some website where I can take the test for free?

Alternatively, is there some simple guide to how the test works so I can re-create it?

Answer (score 2):

There are different varieties of the Token Test (*e.g.*, [Moreira (2011)](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0101-60832011000300003&script=sci_arttext&tlng=en)). Several of them using physical tokens are explained pretty well and can likely be me made at home (*e.g.* [here](http://www.tokentest.eu/en/examples)). I wasn't able to find free digital versions.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Moreira, *Rev psiquiatr clín* (2011); **38**(3)](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0101-60832011000300003&script=sci_arttext&tlng=en)</sub>